# Adding a health bar to a character

Tags: java, image

I need a health bar to decrement according to the character's remaining HP. However I wouldn't
know how to do that because the way my game loads the images

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Textures/Health/Health100.png");
healthBar = ii.getImage();
```

I need it to change to replace 100 in "Health100.png" with the characters current health.
But I don't think I could replace the 100 with a variable so I wouldn't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you could have an image for each level of health and replace the current one with the appropriate one

Comment: 1. Don't use `ImageIcon` when you don't need to... what you want can be accomplished by `Toolkit.getImage`.
2. You can something like `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Textures/Health/Health" + currentHealth + ".png")`

Comment: you could also preload the images into an array and just reference the appropriate one when you need it

Comment: That would be 100 different if statements. I have a texture for each state of the health bar. You start with 100 health. I want to refrain from doing that, so I was making sure there was no other way.

Comment: @LoganStiltner 100 different `if`? says who?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having an Image for each health increment and instead of loading all those images into memory (either one at a time or as a lookup list) you can just create a BufferedImage instance of the right dimensions (width/height) and draw directly onto its Graphics object using the Java2D APIs.  You could refresh the image as the character's health changes without needing to rely on physical image files.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not simply concatenate the health into the string? e.g.

```
int health = 100; // change this variable as appropriate
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Textures/Health/Health" + health + ".png");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can preload the images which will be better than reloading images as health fluctuates.

When you load your game

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
   healthImg[i] = new ImageIcon("Textures/Health/Health" + health + ".png");
```

Then in your game loop

```
 healthBar = healthImg[health];
```

But as the other Jeff suggested, it may be better for you to just not use images (unless your health bar is very fancy)